# How to detect the double tap and hold gesture when accessibility is on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, uitextview

I have an app that displays a link when you scan a QR code.
With accessibility turned on (VoiceOver):
When I double click on the link I open a custom alert.
The problem is that when I double-click and hold on the link I still get the alert instead of the context menu.

My code:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange interaction:(UITextItemInteraction)interaction {

    BOOL linkScheme = ([URL.scheme isEqualToString: @"http"] || [URL.scheme isEqualToString: @"https"]);
    
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:URL]){
        NSUserDefaults *saveURL = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [saveURL setObject:URL.absoluteString forKey:@"SavedURL"];
        [saveURL synchronize];
        
        if (linkScheme) {
//          if (detect double click and hold) {
                return YES;
            } else {
                if(!GUIManager.instance.isAlwaysAskChecked){
                    if(GUIManager.instance.openInThisAppButtonChecked) {
                        UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
                        while (topController.presentedViewController) {
                            topController = topController.presentedViewController;
                        }
                        WebViewController* webView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
                        [topController showViewController:webView sender:nil];
                    } else {
                        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL.absoluteString]];
                    }
                } else {
                    tableV.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
                    
                    AlertView* alertView = [[AlertView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
                    [self.view addSubview: alertView];
                    
                    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, alertView);
                }
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I'd like to enable the context menu on double-click and hold (with accessibility (VoiceOver) enabled), instead of displaying an alert.